# iTunes app verification, new failure started regarding embedded resource bundles on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, codesign

This is new and different.  Have an embedded resource bundle from a 3rd party plugin.  Same bundle has successfully been submitted with this app before on earlier versions.  Yesterday it caused a problem:

> "Unable to process application at this time due to the following
>   error: The bundle 'com.xxxxxx.YYYYY' at bundle path
>   'Payload/example.app/ZZZZZZZ.bundle' is not signed using an Apple
>   submission certificate."

So I tried all the normal signing related fixes, but this is different than anything i could find information about because it relates to a bundle inside the app, not the app itself.  The app itself is signed just fine, and in fact as a test if I remove the bundle, the app verifies fine.

Seems like Apple just introduced some new restriction?  Or has something gone wrong in the codesigning process?

this is done w/ XCode 5.1.1, through the distribute to app store/ validate button in the organizer